# I am trying to convert string to json using JsonConvert.DeserializeObject

Tags: c#, asp.net

I receive this error:

> Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Cannot
> deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into
> type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[OCR.Models.UserDto]' because
> the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize
> correctly.\r\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array
> (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal
> .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection
> type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON
> object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it
> to deserialize from a JSON object.

```
public async Task < List < UserDto >> Post([FromBody] string value) {
    var client = new HttpClient();

    var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
            RequestUri = new Uri("https://microsoft-computer-vision3.p.rapidapi.com/ocr?detectOrientation=true&language=ar"),
            Headers = {
                {
                    "x-rapidapi-key",
                    "8830b90506msha145d86eb92ef41p16ff4djsn74eca27d4951"
                },
                {
                    "x-rapidapi-host",
                    "microsoft-computer-vision3.p.rapidapi.com"
                },
            },
            Content = new StringContent("{\r\n    \"url\": \"https://answers.opencv.org/upfiles/15428940328356049.jpg\"\r\n}") {
                Headers = {
                    ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json")
                }
            }
    };
    using(var response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < List < UserDto >> (body);
        return json;
    }
}
```

this is  UserDto class that i am using :-

```
public class UserDto
{

    public class Words
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }

    }
    public class Lines
    {
        public List<string> boundingBox { get; set; }
        public List<Words> words { get; set; }

    }
    public class Regions
    {
        public List<string> boundingBox { get; set; }
        public List<Lines> lines { get; set; }

    }
    public class Application
    {
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string textAngle { get; set; }
        public string orientation { get; set; }
        public List<Regions> regions { get; set; }

    }
}
```

This is the JSON file:

```
{
   "language":"ar",
   "textAngle":0.0,
   "orientation":"Up",
   "regions":[
      {
         "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
         " lines":[
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               "words":[
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     " text":" مااحي"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               " words":[
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     " text":" الشخصية"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" تحقيق"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"  بطاقة"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               "words":[
                  {
                     " boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"  البشبيشى"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" محمد"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" عدنان"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               "words":[
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" العاشر"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"الحى"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"500,266,75,32",
                     "text":"  زهراء- "
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" ش "
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" ١٠٣٧"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               "words":[
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" القاهره"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"-"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"ثان"
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"نصر "
                  },
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"مدينه"
                  }
               ]
            },
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               "words":[
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":" اا "
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
         "lines":[
            {
               "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
               "words":[
                  {
                     "boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",
                     "text":"$ESO14733"
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried following the advice that the error message gives you?

Comment: The json only describes a **single** `UserDto.Application` instance and not a list of `UserDto`

Comment: BTW The `UserDto` class has no property, so serializing in any direction is useless

Comment: 99% of JSON issues are solved with 5 minutes at https://app.quicktype.io/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message states that your JSON is most likely not a collection but a single object, and it feels like it's of type `Application` (in your code - nested class)

Try changing this:

```
using(var response = await client.SendAsync(request)) {
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        var body = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDTO.Application>(body);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: it returns  empty brackets       {}

Comment: are you receiving {} from the http call?

Comment: that is a different problem then. I thought you are getting JSON you've pasted in the question. You need to check what you are calling with this http client SendAsync, and make sure that works as expected first. Still {} is a single object (even though empty) - you will get an Application or whatever object with all properties set to their defaults.

Comment: yes i received a correct  string from  "response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()"  but i need it in json

Comment: how come you say you get correct response when you get {}? Deserialize means from JSON string to an Object. You won't be creating JSON here, you should have received it from the call. Something there is wrong, so you only get empty response.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231295/discussion-between-morad-maher-and-madoxdev).

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to your mappings there are 2 issues:

1. `"textAngle":0.0` is mapped to `decimal textAngle { get; set; }`, but it needs to be a number;
2. `"boundingBox":"372,266,70,28",` are 3 times mapped to `List<string> boundingBox { get; set; }` but `"372,266,70,28"` is not a collection; it's a string that you would have to divide after deserialisation (or have a custom converter).

Comment: ...and there are no properties in `UserDto` to map anything to!

Answer (score 0):

The JSON is not an array, so you shouldn't expect to deserialize it into a list:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserDto.Application>(body);
```

You made same mistake in your Dto for `boundingBox` properties:

```
public class UserDto
{

    public class Words
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }

    }
    public class Lines
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public List<Words> words { get; set; }

    }
    public class Regions
    {
        public string boundingBox { get; set; }
        public List<Lines> lines { get; set; }

    }
    public class Application
    {
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string textAngle { get; set; }
        public string orientation { get; set; }
        public List<Regions> regions { get; set; }

    }
}
```